# Beamer Table of Contents displays each section on a separate page

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

Using the following code, how can I set TOC to display each section on a separate page.

**The whole TOC pages should appear at the beginning of the document.**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
% == begin Section/Subsection pages control ============
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\newcommand{\subsubsectionpage}{\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection page}}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=0em\rlap{\hskip-2em\textcolor{violet}{\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.}}\textcolor{violet}\inserttocsubsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=2.0em\textcolor{purple}\inserttocsubsubsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \begingroup
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=10pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{section title}
        \usebeamerfont{section title}\thesection-~\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \endgroup
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection page}
{
    \begingroup
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=2pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{section title}
        \usebeamerfont{section title}\thesection-~\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vspace*{-1.pt}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{subsection title}
        \usebeamerfont{subsection title}\thesection.\thesubsection.~\insertsubsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \endgroup
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection page}
{%
    \begingroup
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{subsubsection title}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsubsection title}\thesection.\thesubsection.\thesubsubsection.~\insertsubsubsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \endgroup
}
%= begin defining Section/Subsection title pages
\setbeamercolor{section title}{bg=blue!40}
\setbeamercolor{subsection title}{bg=blue!20}
\setbeamercolor{subsubsection title}{bg=blue!20}
\setbeamerfont{section title}{size=\Large,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subsection title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subsubsection title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}
%= end defining Section/Subsection title pages
% == end Section/Subsection pages control ============
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Section1}
\frame{\sectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection1}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection2}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection3}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection4}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection5}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection6}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\section{Section2}
\frame{\sectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection1}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection2}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection3}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection4}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection5}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection6}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\section{Section3}
\frame{\sectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection1}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection2}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection3}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection4}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection5}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection6}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\section{Section4}
\frame{\sectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection1}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection2}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection3}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection4}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection5}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\subsection{SubSection6}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**instead of the default:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, the following fulfills not 100% what you asked for, but maybe it's enough?

In any case the MWE is using the `part` option for every single section:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Table of Contents I}
        \tableofcontents[part=1]
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{Table of Contents II}
        \tableofcontents[part=2]
    \end{frame}

    \part{A}
    \section{Section1}
    \frame{\sectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection1}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection2}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection3}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection4}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection5}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection6}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    
    \part{B}
    \section{Section2}
    \frame{\sectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection1}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection2}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection3}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection4}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection5}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection6}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \section{Section3}
    \frame{\sectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection1}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection2}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection3}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection4}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection5}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection6}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \section{Section4}
    \frame{\sectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection1}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection2}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection3}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection4}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection5}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
    \subsection{SubSection6}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}
\end{document}
```